# Else statement not printing line?

Tags: java, if-statement, bluej

I wrote a simple program that is supposed to display whether if a user inputted int is a leap year or not, and if so what leap year is it.

During running of the program whenever a number that was not supposed to be a leap year was inputted it did not print the else statement.

Note: This was written in the IDE BlueJ so io was automatically imported hence why I did not import it

```java
/**
 * Reads a user inputted integer value and determines if it is a leap year
 * Created by Oh boy I suck at this
 * 9 September 2019
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear
{
    public static int getYear(String prompt)
    {
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        int value = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(prompt + ": ");
            try
            {
                value = scan.nextInt();
                flag = false;
            }
            catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("What you have inputed was not an int.");
                System.out.println(newLine);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int year = getYear("Input the year ");
        final int leapYear = year/4;
        if(year % 4 == 0){
            if(year % 100 >= 1){
                if(year % 400 >= 1){
                    System.out.println("The year inputted: " + year + " is equivilant to " + leapYear + " leap year(s).");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("The year inputted: " + year + " is not a leap year.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which years are not working? There are a lot of non-leap years that will not be printed because of the outer `if(year % 4 == 0)`.

Comment: Sorry I did not see this until now, but the problem is fixed thank you for your patience and I am extremely sorry for this late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look at your if statements, and remember the rules for leap years.

## Understanding leap years

In general, a leap year is a year that is divisible by four, i.e. where the statement `year % 4 == 0` is true.

But: If a year is not a leap year, when it is divisible by 100. I.e. `year % 100 == 0` is true.

Exception: When that is also divisible by 400, i.e. `year % 400 == 0` is true - then we have a leap year.

Basically: divisible by four yields a candidate - you then have to study it further to make a final decision.

## Decision tree

1. Is it a leap year candidate? `year % 4 == 0` Otherwise: Display "not a leap year"
2. Is it a leap year exception (every 100 years)? `year % 100 == 0` Otherwise: Display "not a leap year"
3. Is it a leap year exception exception (every 400 years)? `year % 400 == 0` True => Display "leap year", False => Display "not a leap year"

## Your implementation

Let's first look at your `if` statement.

1. Your first if statement checks whether the year is divisible by four. This is so that you know whether you deal with a leap year candidate. So this is correct - *but* you forgot to deal with the case, when the year is NOT a leap year (so here you miss a possible "is not a leap year" output)
2. Now it gets a bit confusing. You check whether the year is NOT divisible by 100. If a leap year candidate is NOT divisible by 100 it IS a leap year. So you can output success, but you have to deal with the "else" case.
3. The third if is nested in the wrong if block. It belongs into the else block of the parent.

## Hints

Try to get an understanding on how the input and the output relate to each other and try to hit every if / else.

Whenever you write an if think about whether you need the corresponding else block.

If things get weird, try to "trace" your program with "breadcrumb outputs": System.out.println("1"); System.out.println("2"); ... on every line where you deal with branching or looping (if,else,switch,while...) this will trace every step the program does on the command line. You can use this until your school encourages you to use a proper IDE.

Don't forget: Practice makes perfect ;)

## Pseude code (spoiler)

Only use this if you're completely stuck.

> `if (year % 4 == 0) {`
>
> `// this might be a leap year - we need to dig further`
>
> `if (year % 100 == 0) {`
>
> `if (year % 400 == 0) {`
>
> `print "leap year"`
>
> `} else {`
>
> `print "not a leap year"`
>
> `}`
>
> `} else {`
>
> `print "leap year"`
>
> `}`
>
> `} else {`
>
> `print "not a leap year"`
>
> `}`

## Bottom line

Some of your logic is incorrect and you forget to implement the `else` branches.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the very in depth answer. When I was reading more I finally did figure that part out about leap years. I am just a big dumb dumb and forgot how to calculate them correctly. In the case of the else branches, I did not realize at first but now I do thanks to you and others. I only had one else branch connecting to one if statement and I finally realized that. So instead of nesting, I just made all of the if statements into a single one and required them to be passed yo print the if statement. I'm sorry if that does not make sense my vocab is out of wack but I understand the error.

Comment: But yes, you're completely right I forgot to implement a lot of else branches... Did not really know how nesting works to be honest I just wanted to go ahead make my teacher proud by going ahead. Hence the try catch and while loop for InputMismatchException. But thank you for your contribution I was able yo find out what I did wrong.